# MCA from dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe

```
            name a   b   c   d   e   f
1       220-volt 1   8  12  17  22   8
2     aliexpress 7 133 317 372 358 349
3        bonprix 0   3  14  13  21  11
4       citilink 1  20  40  31  29  30
5            dns 1  16  37  34  39  38
6           ebay 3  32  65  50  55  58
7       eldorado 0  19  76  44  42  56
8        kupivip 0   8  17  24  11  18
9       labirint 0  15  30  34  36  32
10        lamoda 3  25  66  73  68  55
```

and I try to build mca plot.
I use `FactoMineR` and use code

```
library(FactoMineR)
df <- read.table("info.csv", header = TRUE, sep=';')
row.names(df) = df$name
df = df[,-1]
res.mca <- MCA(df)
```

but it returns

```
Error in which(unlist(lapply(listModa, is.numeric))) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the code an reproduced your data.frame ( please use dput, or an other reproducible example ) and got the same error.

When you `?MCA` you will find that x has to be:
`a data frame with n rows (individuals) and p columns (categorical variables)`

After I changed the columns to factors the function runs.

Try this:
`df[] <- lapply(df, factor)`

Tip: use row.names = 1 to set the first column as row names for your data.frame when you read the data.
`df <- read.table("info.csv", header = T, sep = ";", row.names = 1)`